# Errors when link method is used in cakephp 3.5

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to practice the section of [Saving BelongsToMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations) where an example given in the document is to make an association between two existing entities.

I followed below examples in my ArticlesController.php

```
    $this->loadModel('Users');

    $article = $this->Articles->get(2);
    $user = $this->Users->get(1);

    $links = $this->Articles->Users->link($article, [$user]);

    debug($links);
```

*Note: I am getting the values correctly from $article and $user Variables*

after debugging this, i am getting the errors which is 'Unknown method "link" ' where there is no clue from where the link method comes here in the document.
[image: the errors result from ArticlesController]

Thanks in advance for helping & guiding me.

Comment: `$this->Articles->Users` is probably not an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ndm, it seems the BelongsToMany Association were not set. Now it is working. But it should have a clue when an error is raised